# How do I suppress 'GlobalOperationsPOJO' messages in OSB log files?

Tags: weblogic, weblogic11g, osb

I see a lot of spammy messages in the WLS logs that look like this:

```
******************** START DUMP GlobalOperationsPOJO **********************
<xml-fragment xmlns:con="http://www.bea.com/wli/domain/config"><con:monitoring>true</con:monitoring><con:reporting>true</con:reporting><con:logging>true</con:logging><con:sla-alerting>true</con:sla-alerting><con:pipeline-alerting>true</con:pipeline-alerting><con:result-caching>true</con:result-caching></xml-fragment>
******************** END DUMP GlobalOperationsPOJO **********************
```

I assume they're logging the global operational settings that can be seen in the Operations tab of sbconsole.

How do I suppress these messages?

Comment: Not certain if one of these flags, but the alsbdebug.xml and configfwkdebug.xml files in your domain home folder control various debug messages.  See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/admin.1111/e15867/app_debugging.htm#OSBAG732

Comment: What is your exact version of the Oracle Service Bus? There in an Oracle bug in 11.1.1.6.0/11.1.1.7.0 and is fixed in 11.1.1.9.0 that has to do with thosee messages being spammed repeatedly (but to look it up, you need access to oracle support). There are patch downloads if you join oracle support

Comment: That's Bug #16724475, fixed in 11.1.1.7.3 and .4.

However, it looks like it's mostly about the START DUMP log line immediately followed by the END DUMP line with nothing in between, so it might not be the cause.

Comment: BTW his still happens even when everything in alsbdebug.xml and configfwkdebug.xml is set to false. (i.e. the default values)